# Strange behavior when I move a JComponent in a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am in the process of implementing a simple graph editor. It should be possible to create any Node (`Sphere` object) by mouse click and move it by drag and move. It works as far as it goes, but it behaves very strangely. When I click on the node, it slides away from the cursor. The hitbox from every `Sphere` object is strange too, but I can't explain why. Is there a better solution for my code?

This behavior
[image]

```java
public class EditorPanelView extends Panel
{
    private static EditorPanelView instance = null;
    private static GraphController graphController = GraphController.getInstance();

    private EditorPanelView(Color color, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        super(new BorderLayout(), color, x, y, width, height);
        addMouseAdapter();
    }

    private void addMouseAdapter() {
        MouseAdapter mouseAdapter = new MouseAdapter() {
            private Sphere sphere;
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                if (getComponentAt(e.getX(), e.getY()) instanceof Sphere) {
                    sphere = (Sphere) getComponentAt(e.getPoint());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                Sphere sphere = new Sphere(e.getX(), e.getY());
                add(sphere);
                System.out.println("MOUSE CLICKED ON EDITORPANEL; SPHERE CREATED!");
                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                Point p2 = e.getPoint();
                Point loc = sphere.getLocation();
                loc.translate(p2.x - sphere.getX(), p2.y - sphere.getY());
                sphere.setLocation(loc);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                sphere = null;
                System.out.println("Mouse released!");
            }
        };
        addMouseListener(mouseAdapter);
        addMouseMotionListener(mouseAdapter);
    }

    public static EditorPanelView getInstance(Color color, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        return Objects.requireNonNullElseGet(instance, () -> new EditorPanelView(color, x, y, width, height));
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Sphere extends JComponent{
    private int positionX;
    private int positionY;
    private final int width = 50;
    private final int height = 50;

    public Sphere(int x, int y) {
        this.positionX = x;
        this.positionY = y;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
        Graphics2D sphere = (Graphics2D) graphics;
        sphere.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        sphere.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        sphere.fillOval(positionX -(width/2), positionY -(height/2), width, height);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class FrameView extends JFrame {
    private static FrameView instance = null;
    private static final Color FRAMECOLOR = Color.darkGray;

    private FrameView() {
        Dimension size = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        GraphController graphController = GraphController.getInstance();
        getContentPane().setBackground(FRAMECOLOR);
        setTitle("Graph Editor");
        setSize((int) size.getWidth()-200, (int) size.getHeight()-200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new GroupLayout(getContentPane()));

        setJMenuBar(MenuBarView.getInstance());

        add(EditorPanelView.getInstance(Color.LIGHT_GRAY, 260, 53, getWidth()-270, getHeight()-113));
        add(OverviewPanelView.getInstance(Color.gray,  10, 53, 240, getHeight()-113));
        add(ButtonPanelView.getInstance(FRAMECOLOR, 5, 5, getWidth()-10, 42));
    }

    public static JFrame getInstance() {
        return Objects.requireNonNullElseGet(instance, FrameView::new);
    }
}
```

---

```
    public class Panel extends JPanel {
    LayoutManager layout;

    public Panel(LayoutManager layout, Color color, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        this.layout = layout;
        setLayout(this.layout);
        setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        setBackground(color);
    }
}
```

I tried to change the x and y coordinates in `EditorPanelView::addMouseAdapter()`

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [mre]. 2) When strange things happen with a mouse listener (in regard to locations) it is often a problem of adding the listener to the wrong component. 3) Don't extend components and windows unnecessarily. In this case, the `JFrame` is a good example. 4) *"move a JComponent in a JPanel"* Nope! `..EditorPanelView extends Panel`

Comment: Your `Node` should be a plain Java getter/setter class.  You keep a `java.util.List` of `Node` instances in your application model.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay close attention to the [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) section.